# Using an Alfresco Share Form Page, How do I upload a new file with metadata?

Tags: file-upload, alfresco, alfresco-share

I'm working With Alfresco Community Edition.
Here's the code I've tried so far: [Alfresco-Smalgyax](https://github.com/raystorm/Alfresco-Smalgyax).

I have created an **All-in-One Project**, to add a new page to the *create..* menu.  My Page Loads just fine.
I followed, the [Adding a menu item to the "Create..." menu in DocLib](https://docs.alfresco.com/community/tasks/dev-extensions-share-tutorials-add-menuitem-create-menu.html) tutorial, before adding a custom form field and JavaScript to the newly added share page.
I've added a custom field to upload a file to `cm:content`.
I've added some Javascript to get and set the `cm:name` and `mimetype` once an Upload file is chosen.

All the Metadata is correctly ingested.  However, the file is not.

Previously I was successfully, able to upload a file with custom data by following the documentation: [Processing multipart forms](https://docs.alfresco.com/6.2/tasks/ws-forms-process.html).  However, that created a whole new Service endpoint and a custom page that didn't inherit the same look/feel as the rest of the web-application.

The page under *create..* has the same look/feel as the rest of the site. But Upload Fails, Is there a way to leverage the Look/feel of the site and upload a file with metadata and set a custom type in Alfresco?

---

**Clarification**

The `cm:content` field has been customized like so:

```xml
<field id="cm:content" label-id="" mandatory="true">
  <constraint-handlers>
    <constraint type="MANDATORY" event="input"
                validation-handler="Smalgyax.forms.validation.setNameValue" />
  </constraint-handlers>
  <control template="/file.ftl">
    <control-param name="editorAppearance">explorer</control-param>                      
  </control>
</field>
```

[file.ftl](https://github.com/raystorm/Alfresco-Smalgyax/blob/master/smalgyax-share/src/main/resources/alfresco/web-extension/site-webscripts/file.ftl) sets the form input element like so:

```html
<input id="${fieldHtmlId}" type="file" 
       name="${field.name}" 
  <#if field.disabled>disabled="true"</#if> />
```

additionally, `file.ftl` adds custom JavaScript to the page, because I was unable to get it successfully loaded as a separate file using

```xml
<forms>
  <dependencies>
    <js src="/set-name-field.js"/>
  </dependencies>
  <!-- form definition here -->
```

Answer (score 0):

As the Alfresco documentation clearly suggests it won't supports the upload feature. The field type shows **cm:content** that won't accept a file to accept a file even though you have customized and added a explorer option in the code. That is the reason file is not and only content is uploading.

https://docs.alfresco.com/community/tasks/dev-extensions-share-tutorials-add-menuitem-create-menu.html

```
 <field id="cm:content" label-id="">
             <control>
                  <control-param name="editorAppearance">explorer</control-param>
               </control>
   </field>
```

For upload a file , you should use the html component like below,

```
<input type="file" multiple="" name="files[]" class="dnd-file-selection-button">
```

and the javascript should be same as the file-upload.js and dnd-upload.js.

```
http://localhost:8180/share/res/components/upload/file-upload.js

http://localhost:8180/share/res/components/upload/dnd-upload.js
```

Please refer the link below to upload a file through a ajax call.
https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-forum/how-to-upload-a-file-from-a-custom-share-page/td-p/32361